# Android: apply OpenGL effects to camera

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, glsurfaceview, color-blending

Is there any way in Android to use a GLSurfaceView to display the camera preview, while using OpenGL effects on that surface? Specifically additive blending effects. I know OpenGL can use the effects, and I know the camera can be placed on a SurfaceView, but can a camera be placed in a GLSurfaceView and have OpenGL blending effects applied to that camera preview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use camera preview to get the raw pixels of camera frames, then upload it to a texture, and then you can do any effects you want. Try looking at this: [Android Camera OpenGL ES Tutorial](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~ipolok/tam/08_Camera.zip) (android camera support is quite buggy though, it almost never works when used this way).

Comment: @Patrick D have u resolved your issue using this openGl can u share any tutorial or references to apply live camera filters

Comment: Do reference any android & opengl camera

Comment: @AndroEmbedded whatever do you mean?

Comment: @theswine I followed the Android Camera OpenGL ES tutorial.Yes..it's buggy>So, do you have any reference for this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested so far, but [`Camera.setPreviewTexture`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) looks like it was designed for just this kind of job. It directly uses an OpenGL ES texture as the target of preview images, so you can do anything a shader can do with such a texture.